# How to autofill on click an input field with mask in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, mask

This is the span on which user clicks:

```
<span data-content="15" #Fast15   (click)="enterFastTime(Fast15)" class="quick-time">15mins</span>
```

This is my input field, user can manually type the date, or if he clicks the above span he is taking the current time. I have mask which defines the input data to be hh:mm:ss if the users type manually the time

```
<input #time[textMask]="{mask: mask}" (ngModel)="startModel" type="text" placeholder="time" >
```

This is method which is called on user click. Problem is that when I assign the current time in my variable startModel (which is the **ngModel**) it is not displaying the data in the input field, with the console log I am seeing it's in the right format and when the method is over, startModel is again "", I guess the problem is coming because there is a defined textMask.  So the problem is that if user type manually the time it's working, but if he clicks the span to be entered the current time in the input field it's not displaying time in the input field and the data is living only in the execution of the method.

```
public enterFastTime(value) {   
  var date = new Date();    
  var startHours = date.getHours();
  var startMinutes = date.getMinutes();
  var startSeconds = date.getSeconds();
  var autoStart = String(startHours) + ":"+String(startMinutes) +":"+ 
  String(startSeconds);
  this.startModel = autoStart;
  console.log(autoStart);
}
```

Comment: 1.span s  cannot have ngModel. 2. If you wish to two-way bind your input, [(ngModel)]="startModel", one-way: [ngModel]="startModel"

Comment: @Vega my span doesn't have ngModel, I used ngModel in my input field

Comment: 1. What is  (ngModel)="enter15" ? 2. what is [textMask]="{mask: mask}" ? 3. What exactly you are trying to reproduce

Comment: @Vega sorry, my bad, I have forgotten to remove this from the span, this doesn't change the main problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as it's clear from your post and the comment, here is a fix:

HTML:

```
Time now 
<input readonly [ngModel]="startModel" type="text" placeholder="time" >
<br>
Time in 15 min<input readonly [ngModel]="startModelPlus15" type="text" placeholder="time" >
<br>
<button (click)="enterFastTime()" class="quick-time">
  Update
</button>
```

Typescript

```
  startModel;
  startModelPlus15;

  enterFastTime(value) {   
    let date = new Date();    
    this.startModel = date.toLocaleTimeString()

    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (15 * 60 * 1000));
    this.startModelPlus15 = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crrkqc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have fixed value in `span` then you can do something like this in template.

```
<span (click)="time.value = 'hh:mm:ss'">fast15</span>
<input #time>
```

Comment: I have posted a block of code only and maybe it's confussing the situation. When user clicks fast15, I need to fill the input with the current date and fill other input with current date + 15minutes, so there is not a fix value in the span, just when user clicks on the span I need to generate the current date in the input field